# Firebird to SQL Server Migration

Tags: sql-server, firebird

1. Is there a tool native to SQL Server to do the migration (i.e., Import/Export)?
2. Any other options (SSIS).

Please point me to helpful info.

Comment: Hi, Marlon! Can you refine this by saying whether you want to import the schema or just data? There's not a tool to migrate the schema, but you may get better answers if you refine the question to be more specific about just data.

Comment: Also - when I say schema, I mean things like table definitions, indexes, constraints, triggers, etc.

Comment: I do not have the necessary info yet. I'll get back to this when I already have more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL server comes with import / export functionality.  I don't know much about Firebird, but if it support ODBC, you can install the ODBC driver onto your SQL server, and import away.

Comment: Yes, there seems to be an ODBC driver: http://www.firebirdsql.org/index.php?op=files&id=odbc

Answer (score 2):

here is the guide http://forums.devshed.com/firebird-sql-development-61/export-firebird-db-568805.html

also there is fbexport to export to xml/csv forma 
http://fbexport.sourceforge.net/
http://firebirdsql.org/dotnetfirebird/blog/2005/01/fbexport-command-line-tool-for-data.html

ps: maybe i should add an json option :) for it

Answer (score 0):

you could write a quick app that dumps all your data as XML from Firebird. Your SSIS can take it from there. Considering you dont have huge amouts of data, for which Firebird is ideal